# How to get table structure in oracle with constraints?

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

using

```
DBMS_METADATA.GET_DDL('TABLE','PERSON') from DUAL
```

is not working. how to get the meta details of whole schema?

Comment: Maybe you should use the free SQL Developer product.

Comment: It's likely not working for you because you lack the permissions: have you spoken with DBA's so grant you access?

Comment: When asking for help, please consider that "is not working for me " is not a valid error message and conveys no actionable information.  If you are getting an error, please show the error message in context.  If you get no error, but do not get the expected results, then you need to describe that in detail.

Answer (score 1):

In SQL Developer, simply run

```
ddl person
```

We'll run the DBMS_METADATA pl/sql block for you.

You can shape the DDL being generated by using the SET DDL command.

[image]

Then you can see what we're doing down here in the Log panel.

```
select DBMS_METADATA.GET_DDL('TABLE', OBJECT_NAME, OWNER)
  from all_objects
 where owner = :OWNER
   and object_name = :NAME
   and object_type = 'TABLE'
union all
select dbms_metadata.GET_DEPENDENT_DDL('COMMENT', TABLE_NAME, OWNER)
  from (
          select table_name, owner
            from all_col_comments
           where owner = :OWNER
             and table_name = :NAME
             and comments is not null
          union
          select table_name, owner
            from sys.all_TAB_comments
           where owner = :OWNER
             and table_name = :NAME
             and comments is not null
       )
union all
select DBMS_METADATA.GET_DDL('INDEX', INDEX_NAME, OWNER)
  from (
          select index_name, owner
            from sys.all_indexes
           where table_owner = :OWNER
             and table_name = :NAME
             and generated = 'N'
          minus select index_name, owner
                  from sys.all_constraints
                 where owner = :OWNER
                   and table_name = :NAME
       )
union all
select dbms_metadata.GET_DDL('TRIGGER', trigger_name, owner)
  from all_triggers
 where table_owner = :OWNER
   and table_name = :NAME
```

*Disclaimer: I'm a product manager at Oracle, SQL Developer is one of those products I am responsible for.*